# Consolidating multiple duplicated rows of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset comprised of six columns, the first column being a list of Identifiers that match ratios values across the remaining five columns:

```
    Identifier cd_log.ratios cs_log.ratios me_log.ratios pn_log.ratios sm_log.ratios
          A2ICC5     0.3784142            NA            NA            NA            NA
          A2ICC5            NA    -0.4910396            NA            NA            NA
          A2ICC5            NA            NA    -0.1755617            NA            NA
          A2ICC5            NA            NA            NA            NA     0.2279259
          A2ICC8     0.3045490            NA            NA            NA            NA
          A2ICC8            NA     0.2045638            NA            NA            NA
```

Notice for the first four rows, four of the five ratio columns share a duplicated Identifier. How can I consolidate my dataframe to remove duplicated identifiers and shift the ratios to one row? The output would look something like this:

```
Identifier  cd_log.ratios   cs_log.ratios   me_log.ratios   pn_log.ratios   sm_log.ratios
A2ICC5      0.3784142      -0.4910396      -0.1755617              NA       0.2279259
A2ICC8       0.304549       0.2045638              NA              NA              NA
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = '   Identifier cd_log.ratios cs_log.ratios me_log.ratios pn_log.ratios sm_log.ratios
          A2ICC5     0.3784142            NA            NA            NA            NA
          A2ICC5            NA    -0.4910396            NA            NA            NA
          A2ICC5            NA            NA    -0.1755617            NA            NA
          A2ICC5            NA            NA            NA            NA     0.2279259
          A2ICC8     0.3045490            NA            NA            NA            NA
          A2ICC8            NA     0.2045638            NA            NA            NA', header = T)

library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = Identifier]
#   Identifier cd_log.ratios cs_log.ratios me_log.ratios pn_log.ratios sm_log.ratios
#1:     A2ICC5     0.3784142    -0.4910396    -0.1755617            NA     0.2279259
#2:     A2ICC8     0.3045490     0.2045638            NA            NA            NA
```

Comment: Thanks,eddi! I am rather new at R, so I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

eddi's response utilizing `data.table` is great.

In this situation, `melt` and `cast` in `library(reshape)` will also do the work.

```
dfm <- melt(df, id.var='Identifier')
dfm <- subset(dfm, !is.na(value), )
cast(dfm)
  Identifier cd_log.ratios cs_log.ratios me_log.ratios sm_log.ratios
1     A2ICC5     0.3784142    -0.4910396    -0.1755617     0.2279259
2     A2ICC8     0.3045490     0.2045638            NA            NA
```