# Combining (pasting) columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data.frame

```
Tipo Start  End Strand Accesion1 Accesion2
1 gene   197 1558      +      <NA>   SP_0001
2  CDS   197 1558      + NP_344554      <NA>
3 gene  1717 2853      +      <NA>   SP_0002
4  CDS  1717 2853      + NP_344555      <NA>
5 gene  2864 3112      +      <NA>   SP_0003
6  CDS  2864 3112      + NP_344556      <NA>
```

There are more "Tipo" values, such as tRNA, region , exon, or rRNA, but I am only interested in combining these two, gene and CDS

And I would like to get the following

```
Start End Accesion1 Accesion2
1 197 1558 NP_344554 SP_0001
```

but only when the start and End values of gene and CDS coincide. I've tried to use select, arrange and mutate with dplyr, but it is sort of complicated for me to get rid of the NAs

Comment: You may need to provide a bit more details, about whether `gene/CDS` occurs in pairs or not.  It is unclear because you mentioned there are other values `tRNA, region, exon` etc.  Suppose, if `df1$Start[6] <- 2964` what would be the expected result for the example dataset

Comment: Yes, they come in pairs

The solution you gave seems to work very well. Because some extra Tipo are present, some NA appear, but  I can easily discard them with complete.cases

I was looking a solution with dplyr, just because I love it. But the solution (you erased?) works nicely

Comment: Could you check if this works `library(data.table);setDT(df1)[, id:=cumsum(Tipo == 'gene')][,list(Accesion1=na.omit(Accesion1), Accesion2=na.omit(Accesion2)) , list(id, Start, End)]`

Comment: Yes, it is working very well. I got the same results

Comment: basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17328445/817778

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `dplyr` version with `summarize_each`:

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(Start, End) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(max), Accesion1, Accesion2)
```

Produces:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: Start

  Start  End Accesion1 Accesion2
1   197 1558 NP_344554   SP_0001
2  1717 2853 NP_344555   SP_0002
3  2864 3112 NP_344556   SP_0003
```

Assumes `AccessionX` varibles are **character** (does not work with factor), as well as the condition that Start End pairs contain only two values, one each of Tipo and Gene, as in your data set.

Comment: I don't know why but I don`t get it. 
a sapply(df, class) tells me that Accesion1 and 3 are character. But I get this
   Start   End Accesion1 Accesion2
1    197  1558        NA        NA
2   1717  2853        NA        NA
3   2864  3112        NA        NA
4   3196  4311        NA        NA
5   4382  4951        NA        NA
6   4952  8461        NA        NA
7   8519  8785        NA        NA
8   8778  9146        NA        NA
9   9151  9273        NA        NA
10  9266 10534        NA        NA

Comment: I think `summarise_each(funs(max=max(., na.rm=TRUE)), Accesion1, Accesion2)` may be needed

Comment: @akrun, thanks, my data actually had the character versions of `"<NA>"` so it was working fine that way.

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, id:=cumsum(Tipo == 'gene')][,
   list(Accesion1=na.omit(Accesion1), Accesion2=na.omit(Accesion2)) ,
                              list(id, Start, End)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html):

```
df <- data.frame(Tipo=c('gene','CDS','gene','CDS','gene','CDS'), Start=c(197,197,1717,1717,2864,2864), End=c(1558,1558,2853,2853,3112,3112), Strand=c('+','+','+','+','+','+'), Accesion1=c(NA,'NP_344554',NA,'NP_344555',NA,'NP_344556'), Accesion2=c('SP_0001',NA,'SP_0002',NA,'SP_0003',NA) );
df2 <- df[df$Tipo%in%c('gene','CDS'),c('Start','End','Accesion1','Accesion2')];
aggregate(df2[,c('Accesion1','Accesion2')], df2[,c('Start','End')], function(x) x[!is.na(x)] );
##   Start  End Accesion1 Accesion2
## 1   197 1558 NP_344554   SP_0001
## 2  1717 2853 NP_344555   SP_0002
## 3  2864 3112 NP_344556   SP_0003
```

Precomputing `df2` is necessary in case there are non-gene non-CDS rows in the original data.frame; in order to properly aggregate just the gene and CDS rows, the non-gene non-CDS rows must be excluded from both `x` and `by`. (Of course, your example data has only gene and CDS rows, so it's not technically necessary for the example data.)

This solution makes the assumption that whenever two rows have the same `Start` and `End` values, then they must be gene/CDS pairs (as opposed to gene/gene or CDS/CDS).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I didn't check my solution for all the cases as the OP mentioned it works (based on the comments).

Comment: I like this answer as well a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here is one potential way. You choose rows with gene and CDS. Then, you group your data by Start and END. There may be groups of START/END with 1 or 3+ rows. So you want to make sure that you choose START/END groups with two rows. In addition, you want to make sure that you have both gene and CDS (`length(unique(Tipo)) == 2`). Finally, you take non-NA element in Accesion1 and Accesion 2.

```
filter(df, Tipo %in% c("gene", "CDS")) %>%
group_by(Start, End) %>%
filter(n() == 2 & length(unique(Tipo)) == 2) %>%
summarise(Accesion1 = Accesion1[!is.na(Accesion1)],
          Accesion2 = Accesion2[!is.na(Accesion2)])
```

Here is a pseudo example.

```
mydf <- structure(list(Tipo = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CDS", 
"gene"), class = "factor"), Start = c(197, 197, 1717, 1717, 2864, 
2864), End = c(1558, 1558, 2853, 2853, 3112, 3112), Strand = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "+", class = "factor"), Accesion1 = structure(c(NA, 
1L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L), .Label = c("NP_344554", "NP_344555", "NP_344556"
), class = "factor"), Accesion2 = structure(c(1L, NA, 2L, NA, 
3L, NA), .Label = c("SP_0001", "SP_0002", "SP_0003"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Tipo", 
"Start", "End", "Strand", "Accesion1", "Accesion2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")


  Tipo Start  End Strand Accesion1 Accesion2
1 gene   197 1558      +      <NA>   SP_0001
2  CDS   197 1558      + NP_344554      <NA>
3 gene  1717 2853      +      <NA>   SP_0002
4  CDS  1717 2853      + NP_344555      <NA>
5 gene  2864 3112      +      <NA>   SP_0003
6 gene  2864 3112      + NP_344556      <NA>


filter(mydf, Tipo %in% c("gene", "CDS")) %>%
group_by(Start, End) %>%
filter(n() == 2 & length(unique(Tipo)) == 2) %>%
summarise(Accesion1 = Accesion1[!is.na(Accesion1)],
          Accesion2 = Accesion2[!is.na(Accesion2)])

#  Start  End Accesion1 Accesion2
#1   197 1558 NP_344554   SP_0001
#2  1717 2853 NP_344555   SP_0002
```

Comment: @akrun I've been a bit rusty. I wonder the example above clarifies your point. Please let me know if I am missing your point.

Comment: Does this mean that my data.frame must contain factors?. Mine actually does not contain factors. It is a plain data.frame, and your code is not working.

Comment: @AntonioRodriguezFranco It was not clear whether you had character or factor when I saw your question. Let me  revise my suggestion.

Comment: @AntonioRodriguezFranco I tried with a data.frame which contain Tipo, Accesion1 and 2 as character. My code returned the desired outcome. I wonder if something else is going on.